# Инициализация объекта с большим количеством аргументов

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста как можно красиво инициализировать объект obj

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, id, type, number, video, audio):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.number = number
        self.video = video
        self.audio = audio

keys = ['id', 'type', 'number', 'video', 'audio'];

temp = {}

for key in keys:
    print('enter value for ', key)
    value = input('enter value: ')
    temp[key] = value

obj= Record(temp['id'], temp['type'], temp['number'], temp['video'], temp['audio'])
```

в приведённом коде я передал в конструктор 5 аргументов. то есть у каждого указал конкретный индекс. но это не хороший способ потому что при изменении количества атрибутов класса Record придётся менять код в другом месте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему не передать в класс Record просто dict? А конструктор Record проверяет, все ли есть. В этом случае все сильно упроститься.

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.id = data['id']
        self.type = data['type']
        self.number = data['number']
        self.video = data['video']
        self.audio = data['audio']

keys = ['id', 'type', 'number', 'video', 'audio']

temp = {}

for key in keys:
    print('enter value for ', key)
    value = input('enter value: ')
    temp[key] = value

obj= Record(temp)
```

можно пойти ещё дальше и написать хитрый конструктор.

```
keys = ['id', 'type', 'number', 'video', 'audio']

class Record(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for key in keys:
            setattr(self, key, data[key])

temp = {}

for key in keys:
    print('enter value for ', key)
    value = input('enter value: ')
    temp[key] = value

obj= Record(temp)
```

Comment: первый вариант красивее, сразу видно что должен принимать класс

Comment: @LinnTroll

думаю, нужно уточнить, что такое "первый вариант".

Answer (score 2):

```
obj = Record(**temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

если мы имеем функцию или класс вида:

```
def a(q,w,e):
 print(q)
 print(w)
 print(e)
```

то передать в нее значения можно как:

```
a(1,2,3)
```

а так же

```
a(q=1,w=2,e=3)
```

И следовательно просто передав словарь с этими значениями

```
d={"q":1,"w":2,"e":3}
a(**d)
```

во всех 3х случая мы будем иметь один и тот же результат

П.С. надеюсь так будет проще понять. и 2 и 3 вариант использовать предпочтительней, так как вы точно определяете что и куда передаете.